# What do ordinal numbers have to do with 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I Googled "ordinal numbers" and stuff for kids came up, on a website I found.

"An Ordinal Number is a number that tells the position of something in a list, such as 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th etc"

So my question is, what do ordinal numbers in this sense have to do with ordinal numbers in Cantor's set theory?

Comment: They're totally ordered and each ordinal has a successor.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordinal numbers have to do with order (hence the name); which object is *first*, *second*, *third*, and so on depends on what order the objects are arranged in. Likewise, ordinal numbers in the sense of Cantor have to do with the order in which things happen. A good example is the following - consider the following re-ordering of the natural numbers:

$$0,2,4,\ldots, 1,3,5,\ldots$$

This lists the even numbers first and then the odd numbers. It's easy to identify each number with a number indicating its position in this list, at least at first: $0$ is the $1$st element, $2$ is the $2$nd, $4$ is the $3$rd, and so on. But what about $1$? It comes after infinitely many numbers, but it's the *first* number that does. That makes it the $\omega$th element of the list - $\omega$ being the first infinite ordinal. And then $3$ is the $\omega + 1$st, and so on. So **ordinal numbers of whichever sort are numbers which can describe something's location in a list.**

By contrast, a *cardinal* number describes something's size, regardless of order. In English, these are called *one*, *two*, *three*, and so on; these are words which talk about how many things are in a collection, not about what order they're in. If I tell you I have five sheep, I haven't told you anything about how they're arranged. But, as the example above suggests, if I tell you I have $\omega$ sheep, I've accidentally told you something about their order - they can't be arranged like my list above, in two infinite groups, because then I'd have an $\omega + 1$st sheep! So $\omega$ doesn't seem to be the same kind of number as "five". Instead, we use cardinals in the sense of set theory - $\aleph_0$ means "the same quantity as $\omega$, but not in any particular order".

Comment: For completeness it should probably be noted that we don’t always make the notational distinction: $\omega$ is **also** used as an infinite cardinal, in which case it is synonymous with $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Excellent point - I've used that shorthand a lot myself. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer, an [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) describes the [order type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_type) of a [well-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order). A well-order is a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) for which every nonempty subset has a [least element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_element_and_least_element).

Everyday ordinals are just *finite* ordinals. Now, it turns out that [every finite total order is a well-order.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Finite_Totally_Ordered_Set_is_Well-Ordered) Therefore, everyday ordinals describe the order type of finite total orders. That is, we take a finite set and line up its elements in some fashion, and an ordinal describes the position of some element in this arrangement.